# Magento 2: Get Product Stock Quantity and Other Stock Information

Tags: magento2

Magento 2: Get Product Stock Quantity and Other Stock Information

How to get the product stock quantity and information in magento 2

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-product-stock-quantity-and-other-stock-information-by-product-id-in-magento-2/ check details answer.

Answer (score 10):

If we look at the StockItemRepository class the `get` method wants parameter `$stockItemId`, not `$productId`. Reference:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php#L202

I've seen many sites where stock item id IS NOT the same as product id and we should not assume it's the same ID.

To get this working you could use `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item` class instead and load the model by `product_id` field instead. I am also aware of the `website_id` and `stock_id` fields, but as far as I know it's not used (yet) and also existed in M1.

It should look something like this (code not tested):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item;

class Mymodel
{
    /**
     * @var Item
     */
    protected $stockItem;

    /**
     * Mymodel constructor.
     *
     * @param Item $stockItem
     */
    public function __construct(Item $stockItem)
    {
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
    }

    /**
     * Description
     *
     * @param $productModel
     */
    public function getStockQtyByProductId($productModel)
    {
        try {
            $stockItem = $this->stockItem->load($productModel->getId(), 'product_id');

            return $stockItem->getQty();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo 'Something went wrong and was not handled: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

if you have product object then just use following:

```
echo $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

conplete object can be find as follow:

```
var_dump($_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getData());
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually this operation should be performed using **\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface** and here we can obtain **\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface**, by product id or sku and we can use bunch of usefull methods to get stock information - linked product. For general stock information I recommend explore other service contracts declared in **Magento\CatalogInventory\Api**

Example of usage:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Test\Model;
class Test
{
    protected $_stockRegistry;
    public function __construct(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry)
    {
        $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }
    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, as described in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8279)

Comment: You should not use direct `sql` queries in your code.

Comment: this is deprecated as of now.

Answer (score 3):

this code help you to get product quantity

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($productId);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the product object and do not want to use the other classes, You can try in the following way.

```
// For phtml file
$prodObj = $_product->load($_product->getId()); // $_product object in list.phtml
$stockItem = $prodObj->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
$stockQty = $stockItem->getQty(); // $stockItemData = $stockItem->getData();

// For php class file
$stockItem = $prodObj->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
$stockQty = $stockItem->getQty(); // $stockItemData = $stockItem->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Credits:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7057#issuecomment-256052729

Actually \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface
should answer to all your questions.

Long story short:
Magento has StockItem entity which represents amount (Qty) of specific product (productId) on a concrete stock (stockId).
StockItemInterface should be used when you would like to "write" data into the data storage (like update amount of products to sync up Magento with your ERP system or to make deduction of stock during the checkout process).

StockStatusInterface is opposite to it. It should be used to "read" data for representation (on front-end). Consider StockStatus as an index which contains aggregated stock data for each specific product.

So, if you would like to get product stock status (in stock, out of stock) by product_id.
You need using StockStatusRepositoryInterface::getList(StockStatusCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
get StockStatus entity for specified product

```
/** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStatusCriteriaInterfaceFactory $stockStatusCriteriaFactory **/
        $criteria = $stockStatusCriteriaFactory->create();
        $criteria->setProductsFilter($productId);
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusRepositoryInterface $stockStatusRepository **/
        $result = $stockStatusRepository->getList($criteria);
        $stockStatus = current($result->getItems());
        $stockStatus->getProductId();                 // product id
        $stockStatus->getQty();   // quantity of specified product
        $stockStatus->getStockStatus();     // Could be 
// Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status::STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK = 0;
// or
// Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK = 1;
```